# How to upload to sonarqube a java project without maven or gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, sonarqube, jedit

I have downloaded an open-source project, jEdit version 5.5, but it doesn't have maven or gradle. I would like to analyze it using SonarQube, but if I choose the other alternative besides maven and gradle for the analyze, I get an error that I have java files and I should remove them from the analysis. Do you know how I should address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jEdit uses Ant. To analyze an ant project, you can use [SonarScanner for Ant](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarscanner-for-ant/). (Disclaimer: I've never used it myself)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to add a maven pom.xml file. Add a blank [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/martensjostrand/4131573) to the root folder (not src) of the project.